# How can I use database of another system connected in the same network

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, vhosts

me and my friend is working for a wordpress project I want to use his his machine for changing the code and even DB

for that I have changed the host file and httpd-vhost.conf file as follows

****httpd-vhost.conf file***

```
127.0.0.1 wordpress.dev
```

****host file in apache***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "\\Anjana-pc\c\xampp\htdocs\wordpress"
    ServerName 192.168.1.99.localhost
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.99.localhost
    ServerName wordpress.dev
    <Directory "\\Anjana-pc\c\xampp\htdocs\wordpress">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it is not working.

what I want is : whenever I am entering "wordpress.dev" in my Browser I want to access all the  frontend and back end of my the project (we are connected our machine in LAN)

my IP is 192.168.1.10 and my friends PC IP address is 192.168.1.99

thanks in advance

Comment: Change ServerAlias from 192.168.1.99.localhost to ServerAlias wordpress.dev. Put line 192.168.1.99 wordpress.dev to your /etc/hosts file